# ListView with two items per row

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview

I have a listview, and I want something like:

row1: [   item 1   ]

row2: [item2][item3]

row3: [   item 4   ]

row5: [   item 5   ]

etc.

So second and third item to be one next to each other, and other items are standard, one below the other.

I tried to put two items in one row, but that's impossible. I saw this https://github.com/umano/MultiItemRowListAdapter, but it isn't helpful, 'cause I want just two items, others are standard.

Also I tried to make gridview for just two items and listview for others, but then I can't scroll my gridview as I can scroll listview (grid items are always in the screen,I only can scroll my listview, of course). So this would be good if I could somehow connect my grid to list, and to scroll them together, but i can't put scrollview in listview.

Pls help.

Comment: I dont know if it is possible, but what i am thinking is that you can have 2 layout in the second row. that when the (position == 1) have a custom xml-layout infalted that have 2 layouts. then you can make the layout clickable and let each take you to different activity.

Comment: @OsamaEspil is correct. Thats a valid solution. If you post your current code maybe we could give a more specific solution..

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a custom gridview adapter