# Two items inside one row in listview that work with cursors

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have read existing question with two list items per one row here [ListView with two items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817244/listview-with-two-items-per-row)

Problem is similar, but the difference is that I use cursors and I have problem with getting item positions in some cases. I'm trying to achieve this:

```
row1: [item1] [item2]

row2: [gone]

row3: [item3]

row5: [item4]
```

etc.

So I inflated two list items inside first row, then I ask (if position == 1), and inside I put visibility of row2 to gone, and thus it disappears and I achieve situation like mentioned above.  And it works fine on newer versions of android, but strange thing happens on versions 2.3 and below. When I start my Activity, row2 doesn't disappear when I put it on gone and instead it starts changing places with row1(that has two items) every time bindView( ) gets called. It looks like this on my screen:

```
row1: [item1] [item2]
row2: [gone] (I see empty space on screen)
```

and then

```
row1: [gone] (I see empty space on top of the screen)
row2: [item1] [item2]
```

and so on...

And if I put back one item per row everything works fine on every version. So maybe cursor gets confused with getting those positions in newView( ) and bindView( ) functions?

Does anyone know why is this happening?

edit: Here's my cursor adapter class as suggested:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private boolean flag;
    private View headerView;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    // private int positionId;
    private int titleId;
    private int imageId;
    private int iconId;
    private int categoryId;
    private int dateId;
    // private int subcategoryId;
    // private int descriptionId;
    // private int linkId;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

        public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, 0);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        headerView = null;
        flag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        Log.i("bindView", "bindView");

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        // Log.i("bind", "bind view: " + i);
        i++;
        switch (getItemViewType(cursor)) {

        case Constants.view_header:
 //             holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(titleId));
//              imageLoader.DisplayImage(cursor.getString(imageId),
//                      holder.image);
//              // downloader.download(cursor.getString(imageId),       holder.image);
//              break;

            HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;

            if (headerHolder == null) {
                headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) headerView.getTag();
            }               

            if (flag) {
                flag = !flag;
            headerHolder.leftViewHolder.title.setText(cursor.getString(titleId));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(cursor.getString(imageId), headerHolder.leftViewHolder.image);
            }
            else {
                flag = !flag;
            headerHolder.rightViewHolder.title.setText(cursor.getString(titleId));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(cursor.getString(imageId), headerHolder.rightViewHolder.image);
            }
            break;


        case Constants.view_headline:
            holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(titleId));
            holder.date.setText(cursor.getString(dateId));
            if (currentFragmentPosition == 0)
                holder.category.setText(cursor.getString(categoryId));
            imageLoader
                    .DisplayImage(cursor.getString(iconId), holder.image);
            // Log.i("image", cursor.getString(iconId));
            // downloader.download(cursor.getString(imageId), holder.image);
            break;

        case Constants.view_ad1:
            if (!hasRunAd1) {
                // mAdView1.loadAd();
                if (!isTabletDevice()) {
                    initBanner(mAdView1, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_1_ID);
                } else {
                    initBanner(mAdView1, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_1_TABLET_ID);
                }
                hasRunAd1 = true;
            }
            break;
        case Constants.view_ad2:
            if (!hasRunAd2) {
                // mAdView2.loadAd();
                if (!isTabletDevice()) {
                    initBanner(mAdView2, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_2_ID);
                } else {
                    initBanner(mAdView2, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_2_TABLET_ID);
                }
                hasRunAd2 = true;
            }
            break;
        case Constants.view_ad3:
            if (!hasRunAd3) {
                // mAdView3.loadAd();
                if (!isTabletDevice()) {
                    initBanner(mAdView3, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_3_ID);
                } else {
                    initBanner(mAdView3, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_3_TABLET_ID);
                }
                hasRunAd3 = true;
            }
            break;

        default:
            holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(titleId));
            holder.date.setText(cursor.getString(dateId));
            if (currentFragmentPosition == 0)
                holder.category.setText(cursor.getString(categoryId));
            imageLoader
                    .DisplayImage(cursor.getString(iconId), holder.image);
            // downloader.download(cursor.getString(imageId), holder.image);
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.i("newView", "newView");

        // Log.i("bind", "new view: " + j);
        j++;
        View row = null;

        switch (getItemViewType(cursor)) {

        case Constants.view_header:
//              row = inflater
//                      .inflate(R.layout.news_list_header, parent,     false);
//              TextView headerTitle = (TextView) row
//                      .findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_title);
//
//              row.setTag(new ViewHolder((ImageView) row
//                      .findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_image),     headerTitle));
//
//              if (currentFragmentPosition < Constants.headerColors.length)
//                  headerTitle
//                          .setBackgroundColor(Constants.headerColors[currentFragmentPosition]);
//              else
//                  headerTitle
//                          .setBackgroundColor(Constants.defaultHeaderColor);
//
//              break;

            if (headerView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_header, parent, false);

            RelativeLayout leftLayout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_layout_left);
            TextView leftTitle = (TextView) leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_title_left);
            ViewHolder leftHolder = new ViewHolder((ImageView)leftLayout.findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_image_left), leftTitle);

            RelativeLayout rightLayout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_layout_right);
            TextView rightTitle = (TextView) rightLayout.findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_title_right);
            ViewHolder rightHolder = new ViewHolder((ImageView)rightLayout.findViewById(R.id.news_list_header_image_right), rightTitle);

            HeaderViewHolder holder = new HeaderViewHolder(leftHolder, rightHolder);

            row.setTag(holder);

            headerView = row;
            }
            else {
                row = new View(context);
                row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;

        case Constants.view_headline:
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_headline, parent,
                    false);
            row.setTag(new ViewHolder(
                    (ImageView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.news_list_headline_image),
                    (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.news_list_headline_date),
                    (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.news_list_headline_category),
                    (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.news_list_headline_title)));

            RelativeLayout headlineLayout = (RelativeLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.news_list_headline_layout);

            if (currentFragmentPosition < Constants.headlineColors.length)
                headlineLayout
                        .setBackgroundColor(Constants.headlineColors[currentFragmentPosition]);
            else
                headlineLayout
                        .setBackgroundColor(Constants.defaultHeadlineColor);

            break;

        case Constants.view_ad1:
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_ad_item, parent,
                    false);
            mAdView1 = (MoPubView) row.findViewById(R.id.adview);
            mAdView1.setAdUnitId(Constants.CATEGORY_AD_1_ID);

            // row=initBanner(mAdView1, Constants.CATEGORY_AD_1_ID);

            break;
        case Constants.view_ad2:
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_ad_item, parent,
                    false);
            mAdView2 = (MoPubView) row.findViewById(R.id.adview);
            mAdView2.setAdUnitId(Constants.CATEGORY_AD_2_ID);
            break;
        case Constants.view_ad3:
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_ad_item, parent,
                    false);
            mAdView3 = (MoPubView) row.findViewById(R.id.adview);
            mAdView3.setAdUnitId(Constants.CATEGORY_AD_3_ID);
            break;

        default:
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, parent, false);
            row.setTag(new ViewHolder((ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_image),
                    (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_date),
                    (TextView) row
                            .findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_category),
                    (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_title)));

            TextView colorTitle = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.news_list_item_title);

            if (currentFragmentPosition < Constants.headlineColors.length)
                colorTitle
                        .setTextColor(Constants.headlineColors[currentFragmentPosition]);
            else
                colorTitle.setTextColor(Constants.defaultHeadlineColor);

            break;
        }

        return row;

    }

    private void initBanner(MoPubView banner, String id) {

        // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_ad_item, null,
        // false);
        // banner = (MoPubView) v.findViewById(R.id.adview);

        final MoPubView bannerPlace = banner;

        bannerPlace
                .setOnAdLoadedListener(new MoPubView.OnAdLoadedListener() {
                    public void OnAdLoaded(MoPubView paramMoPubView) {
                        bannerPlace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
        bannerPlace
                .setOnAdFailedListener(new MoPubView.OnAdFailedListener() {
                    public void OnAdFailed(MoPubView paramMoPubView) {
                        bannerPlace.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        bannerPlace.setAdUnitId(id);
        bannerPlace.loadAd();

    }

    private boolean isTabletDevice() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) { // honeycomb
            // test screen size, use reflection because isLayoutSizeAtLeast
            // is
            // only available since 11
            Configuration con = getResources().getConfiguration();
            try {
                Method mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast = con.getClass().getMethod(
                        "isLayoutSizeAtLeast", int.class);
                Boolean r = (Boolean) mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast.invoke(con,
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE); // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
                return r;
            } catch (Exception x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // helper for columns from database
    private void initColumns(final Cursor c) {
        if (c != null) {

            // linkId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_LINK);
            // positionId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_HEADPOS);
            titleId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_TITLE);
            imageId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_IMAGE);
            iconId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_ICON);
            categoryId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_CATEGORY);
            dateId = c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_STRINGDATE);
            // subcategoryId =
            // c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_SUBCATEGORY);
            // descriptionId =
            // c.getColumnIndex(SvetDatabase.COL_DESCRIPTION);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        initColumns(newCursor);
        return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position != 0) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
            return getItemViewType(cursor);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // number of view types
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 6;
    }

    // return view type
    private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(SvetDatabase.COL_HEADPOS));
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation is very complete, but it will be great if you can post some code, (of the activity of the custom adapter you could have)since programmers use to identify things faster, since they are used to some patterns in code.

Comment: I posted code, thanks on advice.

Comment: great! i dont have time myself to help you out today, but im sure somebody will. Anywways i will be back tomorrow